# Probability of getting 4 heads when I Toss 12 quarters? mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics

what is the probability of getting at least 4 heads when I toss 12 quarters?

I need a function on mathematica to help me find this. Thank you

Comment: This question has two parts and the first part is a purely statistical question which you do not seem to know the answer to. It should be asked on another site. Its answer pretty obviously answers the sencond part.

Answer (score 5):

```
Probability[x >= 4, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[12, 1/2]]

% // N
```

> ```
> 3797/4096
>
> 0.927002
> ```

Monte Carlo simulation:

```
Count[Total[RandomInteger[1, {1*^6, 12}], {2}], n_ /; n >= 4]
%/1`*^6
```

> ```
> 0.927317
> ```

Reference:  [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) [`Distributed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distributed.html) [`BinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinomialDistribution.html) [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)